# Join on multiple tables where table column has mixed values

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g

Hy guys! For the last few days I've been searching for s solution on the web and SO. It's my first question so please be patient :)

Before the explaining I would like to apologize if  it is too simple, but I've tried everything I could think of and I've got nothing. So, let's start :)

The problem is that in t3_access.auth_id there are values like user_id and group_id, so I need to write a query that will list all the users that are listed in t3_access.auth_id column and also the users that are behind a group in t3_access.auth_id.

Is it even possible to distinguish between users that connected with user_id or group_id in some query? ANY help is more than welcome.

Here is the sqlfiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6dd7/5

I have four tables with their structure:

```
t1_users (user_id, name, pwd_opts)
t2_connections (user_id, group_id, conn_opts)
t3_access (auth_id, class_name, gr_name)
t4_groups (group_id, group_name)
```

Here is the sample data:

```
create table t1_users ("user_id" varchar2(10), "name" varchar2(10), "pwd_opts" varchar2(10));
create table t2_connections ("user_id" varchar2(10), "group_id" varchar2(10), "conn_opts" varchar2(10));
create table t3_access ("auth_id" varchar2(10), "class_name" varchar2(10), "gr_name" varchar2(10), "access" varchar2(10));

create table t4_groups ("GROUP_ID" varchar2(10), "group_name" varchar2(20));

insert into t1_users ("user_id", "name", "pwd_opts", "usr_opts") values ('Peter','Peter Pan','OK','RESTRICTED');
insert into t1_users ("user_id", "name", "pwd_opts", "usr_opts") values ('George','George Michael','OK','NORMAL');
insert into t1_users ("user_id", "name", "pwd_opts", "usr_opts") values ('Danny','Danny Boy','LOCK','SPECIAL');
insert into t1_users ("user_id", "name", "pwd_opts", "usr_opts") values ('John','John Wayne','OK','NORMAL');


insert into t2_connections (user_id, group_id, conn_opts) values('Peter','GROUP1','NORMAL');
insert into t2_connections (user_id, group_id, conn_opts) values('Peter','GROUP2','NORMAL');
insert into t2_connections (user_id, group_id, conn_opts) values('George','GROUP2','SPECIAL');
insert into t2_connections (user_id, group_id, conn_opts) values('Danny','GROUP2','NORMAL');
insert into t2_connections (user_id, group_id, conn_opts) values('John','GROUP3','NORMAL');


insert into t3_access(auth_id, class_name, gr_name, access) values('Peter','class1','PROFILE1','READ');
insert into t3_access(auth_id, class_name, gr_name, access) values('GROUP2','class1','PROFILE2','READ');
insert into t3_access(auth_id, class_name, gr_name, access) values('GROUP3','class3','PROFILE3','UPDATE');
insert into t3_access(auth_id, class_name, gr_name, access) values('George','class2','PROFILE2','EXECUTE');
insert into t3_access(auth_id, class_name, gr_name, access) values('John','class4','PROFILE4','NONE');

insert into t4_groups (group_id, "group_name") VALUES ('GROUP1', 'first group');
insert into t4_groups (group_id, "group_name") VALUES ('GROUP2', 'second group');
insert into t4_groups (group_id, "group_name") VALUES ('GROUP3', 'third group');
```

What I've tried (I've tried UNION, IN, EXISTS between the two selects) but nothing gets me the expected result:

```
select t2_connections.*, t3_access.*
from t2_connections
join t3_access ON t2_connections.group_id = t3_access.auth_id 
where group_id IN (select auth_id from t3_access where auth_id like 'GROUP%');

select t2_connections.*, t3_access.*
from t3_access
join t2_connections ON t3_access.auth_id = t2_connections.user_id
where auth_id IN (select auth_id from t3_access where user_id like 'George' or auth_id like 'Danny' or auth_id like 'Peter' or auth_id like 'John' );
```

...and also I've tried:

```
select t1_users.user_id, t1_users.name, t1_users.pwd_opts, t1_users.usr_opts,
       t2_connections.group_id, t2_connections.conn_opts, t3_access.class_name, t3_access.gr_name,
       t3_access.access
from t2_connections
join t1_users on t2_connections.user_id = t1_users.user_id
join t4_groups on t2_connections.group_id = t4_groups.group_id
join t3_access on t2_connections.group_id = t3_access.auth_id
where exists (select * from t3_access where t3_access.auth_id = t2_connections.user_id);
union 
select t1_users.user_id, t1_users.name, t1_users.pwd_opts, t1_users.usr_opts,
       t2_connections.group_id, t2_connections.conn_opts, t3_access.class_name, t3_access.gr_name,
       t3_access.access
from t2_connections
join t1_users on t2_connections.user_id = t1_users.user_id
join t4_groups on t2_connections.group_id = t4_groups.group_id
join t3_access on t2_connections.group_id = t3_access.auth_id
where exists (select * from t3_access where t3_access.auth_id = t2_connections.group_id);
```

The expected output should look something like this:

```
user_id|name |pwd_|usr_opts    |group_id|conn_opt|cl_name |gr_name   |access
Peter | bla1 | ok | restricted | group1 | normal | class1 | profile1 | read
Peter | bla1 | ok | restricted | group2 | normal | class1 | profile2 | read
George| bla3 | ok | normal     | group2 | special| class2 | profile2 | execute
George| bla3 | ok | normal     | group2 | special| class1 | profile2 | read
Danny | bla4 |lock| special    | group2 | normal | class1 | profile2 | read
John  | bla5 | ok | normal     | group2 | normal | class4 | profile4 | none
John  | bla5 | ok | noraml     | group3 | normal | class3 | profile3 | update
```

Comment: And if you ask a question we might be able to help you.

Comment: first time posting, can't get used to the editor... can't get nice format

Comment: Your example is not working. Some columns do not exist, some column data exceed column widths, some column names do not match case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your example setup being modified as follows ...

```
create table t1_users (user_id varchar2(10), name varchar2(20), pwd_opts varchar2(10), usr_opts varchar2(15));
create table t2_connections (user_id varchar2(10), group_id varchar2(10), conn_opts varchar2(10));
create table t3_access (auth_id varchar2(10), class_name varchar2(10), gr_name varchar2(10), acces varchar2(10));
create table t4_groups (group_id varchar2(10), group_name varchar2(20));

insert into t1_users (user_id, name, pwd_opts, usr_opts) values ('Peter','Peter Pan','OK','RESTRICTED');
insert into t1_users (user_id, name, pwd_opts, usr_opts) values ('George','George Michael','OK','NORMAL');
insert into t1_users (user_id, name, pwd_opts, usr_opts) values ('Danny','Danny Boy','LOCK','SPECIAL');
insert into t1_users (user_id, name, pwd_opts, usr_opts) values ('John','John Wayne','OK','NORMAL');

insert into t2_connections (user_id, group_id, conn_opts) values('Peter','GROUP1','NORMAL');
insert into t2_connections (user_id, group_id, conn_opts) values('Peter','GROUP2','NORMAL');
insert into t2_connections (user_id, group_id, conn_opts) values('George','GROUP2','SPECIAL');
insert into t2_connections (user_id, group_id, conn_opts) values('Danny','GROUP2','NORMAL');
insert into t2_connections (user_id, group_id, conn_opts) values('John','GROUP3','NORMAL');

insert into t3_access(auth_id, class_name, gr_name, acces) values('Peter','class1','PROFILE1','READ');
insert into t3_access(auth_id, class_name, gr_name, acces) values('GROUP2','class1','PROFILE2','READ');
insert into t3_access(auth_id, class_name, gr_name, acces) values('GROUP3','class3','PROFILE3','UPDATE');
insert into t3_access(auth_id, class_name, gr_name, acces) values('George','class2','PROFILE2','EXECUTE');
insert into t3_access(auth_id, class_name, gr_name, acces) values('John','class4','PROFILE4','NONE');

insert into t4_groups (group_id, group_name) VALUES ('GROUP1', 'first group');
insert into t4_groups (group_id, group_name) VALUES ('GROUP2', 'second group');
insert into t4_groups (group_id, group_name) VALUES ('GROUP3', 'third group');

commit;
```

The closest I could get to what you need would be:

```
with all_users$ as (
    select
        U.user_id, U.name, U.pwd_opts, U.usr_opts, C.group_id, C.conn_opts, A.class_name, A.gr_name, A.acces
    from t3_access A
        join t1_users U on U.user_id = A.auth_id
        join t2_connections C on C.user_id = A.auth_id
),
all_groups$ as (
    select
        U.user_id, U.name, U.pwd_opts, U.usr_opts, C.group_id, C.conn_opts, A.class_name, A.gr_name, A.acces
    from t3_access A
        join t2_connections C on C.group_id = A.auth_id
        join t1_users U on U.user_id = C.user_id
    where exists (
            select 1
            from t4_groups G
            where G.group_id = A.auth_id
        )
)
select *
from all_users$ AU
where not exists (
        select 1
        from all_groups$ Gx
        where Gx.user_id = AU.user_id
            and Gx.group_id = AU.group_id
            and Gx.class_name = AU.class_name
    )
--
union all
--
select *
from all_groups$ AG
;
```

Comment: The result should be like I specified in the sample output in the post, the thing is that in your query there are some nulls and there should not be any nulls. I know the design is bad...

Comment: You don't understand. I see that there are NULLs in my query result. I am asking: Why there should not be the NULLs ? Describe in precise and exact english sentences what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Because it's a system that logs user connections. That in place, a user can connect with his user_id or his group_id. I need to get the records where a user connected with his user_id and if he connected with his group_id then the query should return all the users that belong to the group that is in t3.auth_id column (group2 and group3 users). So the query should return the users connected with their user_id and users hiding behind their group_id. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. If that isn't possible with this design, is it possible to alter the design to achieve this kind of query?

Comment: No problem. A mental exercise for me. :-)

OK, I updated my answer based on your specification. The query still does not return what you require. Are you sure you know what you need ?

Comment: maybe it's impossible due to bad design... 
I need to get all the user connections that connected to a target db. Whether he connected with his id or his group_id, so the result should list all the user_id-s. It's a weird task because I don't have access to the data model, but he model can be altered but I don't know how to achieve this... I appreciate the your effort

Comment: Here you are, I updated my answer. Now it returns what you need.

Comment: if a user connected via his user_id then it should display the group_id depending on the class_name and gr_name.
But I don't know if there is a table where class_name and gr_name are PK's, that would restrict the output?
My main problem is that I don't have access to the data model and I have to work only with this provided data. Are there any modifications that I could do to get this kind of output?

Comment: Based on the table definitions, I see no such thing as "group_id depending on the class_name and gr_name", sorry. The table definitions lack any relationship+uniqueness information; nothing can be said about those data.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOOOO MUCH, this kind of query was too much for my skills, thank you very very much for your time and effort! If you ever visit Croatia, you have many drink waiting for you :D

Comment: It's pretty close from Slovakia. I might take advantage of your offer. :-D